# Master page for user profile pages, how that works?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

I am building a SharePoint intranet branding solution, I have built 2 master page for site and system. Planning to build another master page for users but noticed each user has a different site collection and publishing features are also not enabled, How usually profile master pages are built? Can I use only one site collection for all users? Do I need to copy master pages and other stuf in each site collection?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use 1 site collection for all. Each profile has its own site collection.

You need to have MySite specific solution where you have a Web scoped feature that adds the masterpage to the masterpage gallery and sets the masterpage for the site collection through the `FeatureActivated` eventreceiver.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need feature stapling to brand all the personal My Sites. The process remains similar to 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the master page directly using a httpmodule .

The PreRequestHandlerExecute method fires just before ASP.NET starts executing a page. In the context_PreRequestHandlerExecute method, you can get the current executing page by accessing the CurrentHandler object.

PS:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page

If each and every profile needs a different master page better do it using css changes .