# Different ways to automatically apply branding when a site is created

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, branding

I'm wondering if there is another way to automatically apply custom branding when a site is created? besides the following:

- Feature stapling
- Event receiver (Web provisioned)

On SP 2010...

Another related question, Does web template files (from "Save as template" option) could have attached the branding within the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty much the options or manually apply it via powershell etc

You are using the SharePoint 2010, you can think about the sandbox solutions using event handler named `WebProvisioned`.

[Deploying Branding Solutions for SharePoint 2010 Sites using Sandboxed Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg447066(v=office.14).aspx)

Most of the objects in a site are included and supported by the template. There are a number of objects and features not supported however.

**INCLUDED IN USER SOLUTION WSP**

- Lists
- Libraries
- External Lists
- Data source connections
- List views and data views
- Custom forms
- Workflows
- Content Types
- Custom Actions
- Navigation
- Site pages
- Master pages
- Modules
- WebTemplates

**NOT INCLUDED IN USER SOLUTION WSP**

- Customized permissions
- Running workflow instances
- List item version history
- Workflow tasks associated with running workflows
- People/group field values
- Taxonomy field values
- Publishing pages and publishing sites
- My Sites

more details: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx#_Toc258332696

Comment: Yeap, the WSP with a custom branding worked!... 

I knew about the "WebProvisioned" event but my client doesn't want that, thats why I ask for other options... 

Thanks

Comment: Just for the record, if you want to use the WSP web template on another site collection, first you need to activate all the features that were activated when you saved the template.

Comment: Yup without activation you will not see in option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use httpmodule to apply branding or set different master pages .

PS:[Master page for user profile pages, how that works?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108689/master-page-for-user-profile-pages-how-that-works/108795#108795)

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108689/master-page-for-user-profile-pages-how-that-works/108795#108795